# How to show $e_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}$ is standard orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,2\pi]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I find the conclusion in a book, but without proof. It say that  $e_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{int}$ is standard orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,2\pi]$. I can prove that
$$
\lVert e_n \rVert =1
$$
and
$$
(e_n,e_m)=\delta_{nm}
$$
But I don't know how to show it is a basis, namely, for any $u\in L^2[0,2\pi]$, the $u$ can be presented as
$$
u=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty  (u, e_i) e_i.
$$
I know it is equal to prove the Parseval equation, namely
$$
\lVert u \rVert^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |(x,e_i)|^2.
$$
Or equal to prove
$$
\{e_n\}^\bot=\{\theta\}.
$$
But no one of them I can prove.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of [Fourier Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Complex-valued_functions)? It more or less says that functions on $[0,2\pi]$ can all be written as a (bi-infinite) sum of exponentials. That is, $\{ e^{inx} \}$ is a basis (when we allow infinite sums).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor  Thanks. I am not familiar with it. Let me take some time to learn it. Do you mean the Fourier Series in book of  mathematical analysis for freshman (student of first year undergraduate)?

Comment: Yes. If you're looking for a quick and readable reference, I'm partial to Tom Leinster's notes on the subject (see [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/fa/fa_notes.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the orthogonal complement is non-zero, containing $f$.

Think to it as a $2\pi$-periodic function. The shifts of $f$ are in the orthogonal complement too. For the right choice of $\phi$ continuous we get that $g(t) = \int_0^{2\pi} f(t-u)\phi(u)du$ is non-zero, continuous, and orthogonal to every $e^{int}$.

But if $g(a)\ne 0$ then for $m$ large enough $\int_0^{2\pi} g(t) \left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^mdt$ can't be $0$, contradicting that $g$ is orthogonal to the exponentials.

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to understand you.  Could you talk about it detail ?  For example, how to choice $\varphi$ such that $g(t)$ is non-zero and orthogonal to $e^{int}$.  And why  $\int_0^{2\pi} g(t) \left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^mdt$ can't be $0$, when $m$ is large enough.

Comment: For all $\phi$ then $g$ is orthogonal to every $e^{int}$ so it suffices to choose it such that $g$ is non-zero. And $\int_0^{2\pi} g(t) \left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^mdt$ is non-zero because $\left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^m$ is almost zero away from $a$ so $\int_0^{2\pi} g(t) \left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^mdt\approx  \int_0^{2\pi} g(a) \left(\frac{1+\cos(t-a)}2\right)^mdt$